# Network request fail when building on iPhone X

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I use react native to build an iOS project. It works fine in the simulator, but when I tried to build it on my iPhone X, it shows network request fails and cannot log in.

When I build the code on Xcode, I log in my apple ID and set as the development team.

Is there anything that I need to do on my iPhone or Xcode to use it on iPhone?

Comment: What error messages exactly are you getting? "Network request fails" isn't particularly useful. Do you have WiFi turned on? SIM card allowing data access? Are you on the same network?

Comment: I've the same error. In iPhone X emulator works fine but, in device I can't login into app...